# Maximum power available of a generator derivation

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, maximum-ratings

I'm having a hard time with the maximum power disposable from a generator derivation, it's something that I should know but I'm confused about it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMUocM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My Professor started with this circuit and the complex power
$$W_g= \frac{V_g I_g^*}{2}$$
Where \$V_g\$ and \$I_g\$ are phasors, he then said \$I_g=\frac{V_g}{Z_g+Z_a}\$, then we hypotize the MPT condition (Maximum Power Transfer) so \$Z_g=Z_a^*\$.

Now we have $$I_g=\frac{V_g}{2R_g}=\frac{V_g}{2R_a}$$

At this point we can substitute the Ig in the formula of power obtaining:
$$W_g= \frac{V_g I_g^*}{2}= \frac{|V_g|^2}{8R_g}$$
Ok so the result is correct but the mathematical passage is not clear to me, because if you substitute the current there is a 2 factor that doesn't show in the math.

## Edit with solution

The problem was stupid because i named Vg over the resistor and the Vg of the  voltage generator the same, I had to use the voltage partition formula over \$ R_g\$ to get the \$V_{g_{resistor}}\$ and then multiply it by the current.
in formulas:
we have (MPT) $$I_g=\frac{V_g}{2R_g}=\frac{V_g}{2R_a} $$
$$V_{g_{resistor}} =\frac{R_g}{R_g+R_a}V_g = \frac{V_g}{2}$$
$$W_g= \frac{V_{g_{resistor}} I_g^*}{2}=\frac{V_{g} I_g^*}{4}=\frac{|V_g|^2}{8R_g}$$

Comment: Why don’t you interrupt and ask in class, MPT is always when Zs=Zload

Comment: You can differentiate : where the derivative is zero ( in a quadratic eqn) you either have a minimum or a maximum.

Comment: The MPT condition are in the hypotesis, i'm talking to derive the disposable power of a generator when in MPT

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thats impedence adaption

Comment: I think you mean "maximum power available".  "Disponible" or "a disposizione" = available, not disposable.

Comment: @Sergio Piccione  "Ok so the result is correct but the mathematical passage is not clear to me" how do you know that result is correct ,is it given in book ? Can you show it ?

Comment: @SergioPiccione - Hi, Thanks for coming back with the solution. :-) On Stack Exchange, solutions should not be added into the question. Instead, please remove the solution from the question, and instead write your own answer containing the solution. Then, if that is the best answer to your question, you can accept it (i.e. click the "tick mark") to close the topic after 2021-03-23 at 18.18 UTC (i.e. no sooner than 48 hours after you asked the question). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MPT occurs when the voltage is 1/2 the no load voltage in a linear system. (In PV current sources it’s about 70 to 82%)

**In theory (and practise) MPT is when conjugate complex impedances are matched.**

\$P_{total}=(\dfrac{V_g^2}{R_g+R_L})=\dfrac{V_g^2}{2R_g}\$ since both R’s are equal.

But the generate absorbs 50% of the MPT and only “generates” 50% into the load so the Pg is 1/4Rg not 1/8Rg.

;) tell your Prof you found a discrepancy, he might hire you for a job.

This is the MPT, but far from optimal efficiency but then is used in most RF with matched impedances.

I have never seen nor used his formula. I am not responsible if you apply his formula to a nuclear reactor (lol) but they are only 50% efficient from cooling and other losses.

Comment: Wzg=Pvg/4Rg in MTP condition, in my case Pvg is A^2/2 it's a sine, so it has to be with the 8

Comment: Ok I was assuming RMS for everything not peak since it was  not spec’d. Gen’s are usually defined that way.